# Correctly display a child view controller depending on the orientation

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

I am trying to create a facebook component (subclass of UIViewController) to share picture. A demonstration of its state now can be found here : 
http://jeremy.gabriele.free.fr/SO/rotatesubvc/

Integrated inside a ViewController, I would like to use it this way :

```
_shareSheet = [[FBSharePictureViewController alloc] initWithImage:self.currentImage.image andDelegate:self]; // Create the instance
[_shareSheet showWithinViewController:self]; // Actually display the sheet with animation
[_shareSheet hide]; // When needed, hide with animation
```

The view architecture :

```
- [UIView] view
-- [UIView] overlay, a full-screen black view (when showWithinViewController: is called, slightly fade in to alpha 0.8)
-- [UIView] _sheetViewContainer, contains the sheet
---- [UIView] topView, contains the cancel and post buttons + a centered label
---- [UIView] bottomView, contains the picture we will share + an UITextView the user can enter text in.
-- spinner, an UIActivityIndicatorView
```

The showWithinViewController function :

```
- (void)showWithinViewController:(UIViewController *)parentViewController {

  [parentViewController addChildViewController:self]; // So the parent will foward actions like rotation,...

  // I want it to match the full size of my screen, so if we have a transparent
  // status bar the overlay will be visible under the status bar too
  CGRect frameBefore = self.view.frame;
  [parentViewController.view addSubview:self.view]; // view frame = {{0, 0}, {320, 460}}
  self.view.frame = frameBefore; // view frame = {{0, -20}, {320, 480}}

  self.view.hidden = NO;

  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
    // _sheetViewContainer.frame is originally centered horizontally and y is offscreen
    _sheetViewContainer.frame = [self getSheetViewFinalPos]; // I want the sheet to be centered between the UINavigationBar and the UIKeyboard
    self.overlay.alpha = 0.8f;
  } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    self.cancelButton.enabled = YES;
    self.postButton.enabled = YES;
  }];
```

}

The getSheetViewFinalPos function :

```
- (CGRect)getSheetViewFinalPos {
  CGFloat keyboardHeight = UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]) ? 216 : 162;
  CGFloat navBarHeight = UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]) ? 44 : 28;

  CGRect f = _sheetViewContainer.frame;
  f.origin.y = navBarHeight + 20 + (self.view.frame.size.height-20-navBarHeight-_sheetViewContainer.frame.size.height-keyboardHeight)/2;
  return f;
}
```

**Now my problem :** (You could have a preview if you visited the link above :))

I'd like to find the best way for my component to resize its frame automatically depending on the orientation.

- I've tried `UIAutoresizingMask` but it had really strange behaviors and I couldn't succeed in making it work :/.
- I've tried to use `viewWillLayoutSubviews` method but this doesn't work if my view is hidden (when I rotate and the view is not shown).
- I've tried to use didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation but when the parent ViewController is initially on landscape mode and I show my component, it's displayed in portrait mode.

How would you do to achieve this ?

Comment: how did you try do set `UIAutoresizingMask`?

Comment: In brief, set overlay to flexibleWidth|flexibleHeight (so it's always fullScreen), _sheetViewContainer to allFlexible (margins+width, so the size + the position will change), and topView/bottomView to flexibleWidth|flexibleHeight. All is totally messed up (go to the link above, 2nd video). But I also use layermask to achieve the round corners effect, do you think it can be the problem ?